# Como adicionar valores de várias strings a outra sem que essa string perca seu valor?

Tags: jquery, concatenação-de-string

estou querendo ir adicionando valores a uma variável dentro de um for da seguinte forma:

```
function gerarcods(){
    var alfa = $("#nalfa").val();
    var qtdcods = $("#nqtdcods").val();
    codigos = "";
    for(i = 1; i<= qtdcods; i++){  
        str = alfa+i+",";
        res = codigos.concat(str);
    }
 }
```

Porém, dessa forma, o valor de res é sobreposto(obviamente). O intuito é que a string fique assim: "alfa1,alfa2,alfa3...".
Gostaria de saber se há uma função para adicionar um conteúdo a string sem que eu perca seu valor anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque um operador na frente dessa:

```
str += alfa+i+",";
```

Acredito que essa parte da funnção pode ir depois do `for` e não dentro:

```
res = codigos.concat(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa definir a variável `res` antes e ir concatenando com `+=`. Mas não vi a necessidade da variável `codigo` nem do método `concat`:

```js
function gerarcods(){
    var alfa = $("#nalfa").val(),
        qtdcods = $("#nqtdcods").val(),
        res = '';
    for(i = 1; i<= qtdcods; i++){  
        res += alfa+i+",";
    }
    
    console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nalfa" value="alfa">
<input type="number" id="nqtdcods" value="2">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="gerarcods()">Gerar</button>
```